# Using checkbox to decide which input boxes value to sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write some Javascript/jQuery to sum the value entered in multiple text boxes.

Each input box has a checkbox associated with it, and based on that checkbox the value will be added to the total. For example, if the user selects `Activity fees` and `Transport fees` they should add up, if he selects `Misc fees` that will also add up, and if he then unchecks `Misc fees`, that value should be subtracted again.

```js
function optionalfee() {
    var total = 0;
    var fee = document.getElementsById('optional1');
    for (var i = 0; i < fee.length; ++i) {
      if (optional1.checked == true)
        document.getElementById('optional').value = fee;
      total += parseFloat(fee.value);
    }
  } else {
    total -= parseFloat(fee.value);
  }
  //alert(total);
document.getElementById('toptional').value = total;
}
```

```html
Include Activity fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional1" /><input type="number" id="optional" name="afees"><br><br>
Include Transport fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional1" /><input type="number" id="optional" name="tfees"><br><br>
Include Misc fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional1" /><input type="number" id="optional" name="mfees"><br><br>
Include Olympiad fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional1" /><input type="number" id="optional" name="ofees"><br><br>
Optional fees total <input type="number" id="toptional" name="toptional" class="toptional" readonly>
```

Comment: You should have only one element with `id="optional1"`

Comment: "can't seem to get it working" isn't really a meaningful description of a problem.  In what way does it fail?  Also, as mentioned in another comment (and likely more to come), the HTML is invalid.  So the behavior of any JavaScript is going to be undefined until that's corrected.  `id`s need to be unique.

Comment: Formatting your code shows you have syntax errors - missing a bracket after `if (optional1.checked == true)` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. made all IDs unique
2. used classes instead
3. added missing brackets
4. tested values for isNaN and empty
5. also update when number changes

Note I am using data attributes for the id

Plain JS:

```js
function optionalfee() {
  var total = 0;
  // get the checked boxes only
  document.querySelectorAll('.optional:checked').forEach(check => {
    // find the ID of the input to use
    var input = document.getElementById(check.getAttribute("data-id"));
    var val = input.value;
    // handle poor or no input - is in principle already handled by the type="number"
    val = (isNaN(val) || "" === val.trim()) ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
    total += val;
  })
  document.getElementById('toptional').value = total;
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const checks = document.querySelectorAll(".optional"),
    fees = document.querySelectorAll(".fee");
  checks.forEach((check, i) => {
    checks[i].onclick = optionalfee;
    fees[i].oninput = optionalfee;
  })
})
```

```html
Include Activity fees

<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional1" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional1" name="afees">
<br>
<br>Include Transport fees
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional2" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional2" name="tfees">
<br>
<br>Include Misc fees
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional3" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional3" name="mfees">
<br>
<br>Include Olympiad fees
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional4" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional4" name="ofees">
<br>
<br>Optional fees total
<input type="number" id="toptional" name="toptional" class="toptional" readonly>
```

jQuery:

```js
function optionalfee() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.optional:checked').each(function() {
    var val = $("#"+$(this).data("id")).val();
    val = isNaN(val) || "" === $.trim(val) ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
    total += val;
  });
  $('#toptional').val(total);

}

$(function() {
  $(".optional").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", optionalfee);
    // if not next to each other, 
    // use  $("#"+$(this).data("id")).on("input", optionalfee);
    $(this).next().on("input", optionalfee);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Include Activity fees
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional1" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional1" name="afees">
<br>
<br>Include Transport fees
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional2" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional2" name="tfees">
<br>
<br>Include Misc fees
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional3" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional3" name="mfees">
<br>
<br>Include Olympiad fees
<input type="checkbox" class="optional" data-id="optional4" />
<input type="number" class="fee" id="optional4" name="ofees">
<br>
<br>Optional fees total
<input type="number" id="toptional" name="toptional" class="toptional" readonly>
```

Comment: 1. Limited number of lookups since it's only the checked boxes that are used. 2. JQuery version does not do that but looks at the next - that however assumes the check box will stay next to the input. Swings and roundabouts... My solution can be tweaked to use data-id in both cases. Also semicolons are optional unless you need to minify-  == also works just fine. I'll update just for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="afees" class="sum-checkbox" />
<input type="number" id="optional" name="afees">
```

assign `input#number` `name` as id of corrsponding checkbox.
add one common class `(e.g. sum-checkbox)` for required checkbox.

```
var sumAll = 0;
$(".sum-checkbox").on('change',function(){

    var currentCheck = $(this);
   var checkId = $(currentCheck).attr('id');
    if(currentCheck.prop('checked')){

        sumAll += parseInt(inputVal);

    }else{
        sumAll -= parseInt(inputVal);
    }


})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` should be unique in same document but you could achieve what you want without using those ids, check the example below using `:checked` to get the checked checkboxes then `each()` to go through them and calculate the total.

Hope this helps.

```js
function calculate_sum() {
  var total = 0;
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    total += parseInt( $(this).next('input').val() );
  })

  $('#toptional').val(total);
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  calculate_sum();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Include Activity fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional11" /><input type="number" id="optional1" name="afees"><br><br>
Include Transport fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional22" /><input type="number" id="optional2" name="tfees"><br><br>
Include Misc fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional33" /><input type="number" id="optional3" name="mfees"><br><br>
Include Olympiad fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional44" /><input type="number" id="optional4" name="ofees"><br><br><hr>
Optional fees total <input type="number" id="toptional" name="toptional" class="toptional" readonly>
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria Achkari can you please help me in understanding the javascript ?

Comment: I would not use the change event on checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript to sum the value entered in multiple number inputs every time an element `checkbox` or `input` receive click or input respectively:

```js
var total = document.getElementById('toptional'),
    checkboxs = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox'),
    inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('fee'),
    getTotalFee = function() {
        var totalFee = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = checkboxs.length; i < len; i++) {
            checkboxs[i].checked && (totalFee += +inputs[i].value);
        }
        total.value = totalFee;
    };

for (var i = 0, len = checkboxs.length; i < len; i++) {
    checkboxs[i].addEventListener('click', getTotalFee, false);
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input', getTotalFee, false);
}
```

```html
Include Activity fees: 
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="number" name="afees" class="fee"><br>

Include Transport fees: 
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="number" name="tfees" class="fee"><br>

Include Misc fees: 
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="number" name="mfees" class="fee"><br>

Include Olympiad fees: 
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="number" name="ofees" class="fee"><br>

<br><br><hr>

<strong>Optional fees total:</strong>
<input type="number" id="toptional" name="toptional" value="0" class="toptional" readonly>
```

Comment: Why create a new method when one is available to all modern browsers, even browsers that does not understand addEventListener? I fail to see why this is THE accepted answer taking into account the other issues explained in my answer.

Comment: The method was just to return an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of elements by class name and it works.. Now updated to iterate with a `for` loop..

Comment: By the way, check the method again: `var arrFromList = ClassName => [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(ClassName));` It works well and returns an array instead of a a NodeList instance, or a superset of the NodeList (FF, for instance returns an instance of HTMLCollection).

Comment: Sure but there are TWO methods - getElementsByClassName AND querySelectorAll already working great :) and I don't like the addEventListener since it is not working the same or at all in some browsers

Comment: The `addEventListener()` method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, and Opera 6.0 and earlier versions. However, for these specific browser versions, you can use the `attachEvent()` method to attach event handlers

Comment: Or onclick in all browsers supporting JS

Comment: Why bother? That is what I already used in my answer from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

First I notice that you are setting  id="optional1" to many elements, remember id is identifier and it should be unique in the html document.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function optionalfee(){
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i<=4; ++i){ 
        var fee = document.getElementById('optional'+i);
        if(fee.checked==true){
            total += parseFloat(document.getElementById('optional-fee'+i).value);
        }
     }
    //alert(total);
    document.getElementById('toptional').value = total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Include Activity fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional1" onclick="optionalfee()" /> <input type="number" id="optional-fee1" name="afees"><br><br>
Include Transport fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional2" onclick="optionalfee()" /> <input type="number" id="optional-fee2" name="tfees"><br><br>
Include Misc fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional3" onclick="optionalfee()" /> <input type="number" id="optional-fee3" name="mfees"><br><br>
Include Olympiad fees <input type="checkbox" id="optional4" onclick="optionalfee()" /> <input type="number" id="optional-fee4" name="ofees"><br><br>
Optional fees total<input type="number" id="toptional" name="toptional" class="toptional" readonly>
<input type="button" onclick="optionalfee()" value="sum" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesnt seems to work as when I uncheck box the value doesnt calculate correctly.

Comment: to calculate you need to click on button sum.

Comment: or else if you want to calculate on click of checbox the add event onclick="optionalfee()" in each check box